# LyX with XeTeX refuses to use the italics version of David CLM

Tags: fonts, xetex, lyx, hebrew, emphasis

I've been using a setup of LyX with XeTeX on my laptop and it's been working just fine. However, I installed it on my desktop (with the same fonts, packages, everything) and I've noticed that whenever I try to use emphasis (\emph) on Hebrew text it just doesn't work.

The problem seems to be specifically with the font David CLM, which is the default roman font and works fine on my other computer. With any other font set as the default, the problem disappears. I tried reinstalling the font on my desktop, and the italics option works fine in MS Word and other places, but when I try to emphasize text in LyX (and the same with making it slanted and italics via the menu) the output is just normal text.

If it isn't clear from the first paragraph, the LaTeX preamble is the same as the one on my laptop (which does work correctly) but I attached it here just in case:

```
%%% Set Hebrew and English fonts
\setmonofont[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
%\newfontfamily{\englishfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
% Proper font size in math mode.
\setmathrm[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Math}

%%% Another way is to set just the Hebrew fonts:
% \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
% \newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
% \newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
% consider using \usepackage{iffont}

%%% Sets both header and footer
\fancyhf{} % sets to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textup{\thepage}}

\renewcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}

%%% Some alternative styles
\ifcsname question\endcsname
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{quesh}[thm]{שאלה}
  \renewenvironment{question}{\begin{quesh}}{\end{quesh}}
\else
\fi
\ifcsname sol*\endcsname
  \theoremstyle{remark}
  \newtheorem*{emphsol*}{פתרון}
  \renewenvironment{sol*}{\begin{emphsol*}}{\end{emphsol*}}
\else
\fi

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii})}
```

Comment: after you reinstalled the font try to reconfigure lyx, by using `tools -> reconfigure`

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show any active setting regarding `David CLM`. It is quite unclear how you use the font.

Comment: @Yorgos I tried using it now, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer David CLM is used as the roman font in Document > Settings > Fonts > Roman. As far as I know this should have the same effect of uncommenting the line `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}` in the preamble, which I tried but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have lyx. You should provide a small complete example code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Could you please clarify what you mean by that? I'll provide anything you need

Comment: Hello @HagaiM, Could you provide a minimal LyX file that demonstrate the problem? Note that a LyX file is a text file, so you can open it with any text editor (instead of using LyX.exe) and post it's content.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your `.log` file for warning messages about any fonts not being found.

Next, make sure you’ve [downloaded and installed the Culmus fonts,](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/download.html) including `DavidCLM-MediumItalic.otf`.  You might want to re-run `fc-cache -f -s -v` and `luaotfload-tool -f -u -p -v` to make sure they’re indexed.

Finally, you might load the fonts by filename:

```
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{DavidCLM}[
  Script = Hebrew ,
  Ligatures = Discretionary ,
  UprightFont = *-Medium ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-MediumItalic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
  Extension = .otf ]
```

Some installations may use the extension `.ttf` or have a different filename, so one way around that would be to move these definitions to a file named `DavidCLM.fontspec`:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[DavidCLM]{
  Ligatures = Discretionary ,
  UprightFont = *-Medium ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-MediumItalic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
  Extension = .otf
}
```

You could then use `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{DavidCLM}[Script=Hebrew]` or `\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Language=Default]{DavidCLM}`.  If you ever need to compile on an installation with `.ttf` filenames, you can then edit only the `.fontspec` file.